# removeClass function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, removeclass

I wrote functions that allow the user to select and de select divs by clicking on them. Now, what i was trying to do was a function that, once pressed *a*, deselects everything, but it only deselect *some* of my divs. Here is the code:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('fuori');
for(i = 0, j = divs.length; i < j; i++){
 divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(!hasClass(this, 'selected')){
    this.className = this.className + " selected";
} else {
    removeClass(this, 'selected');
}
});
}
```

removeClass function is this

```
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
        ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}
```

and this is deselectAll

```
function deselectAll(){
    var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
    alert(selected.length);
    for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
        removeClass(selected[i], 'selected');
    }
}
```

Selecting and deselecting by clicking works seamlessly, but when i select some divs and press *a* it doesn't deselect every div, but only some of them.

How could i fix this? and why doesn't it work?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't want to, i want to practice vanilla javascript not to forget how to write it, and don't want to load lots of un-needed features.

Comment: Fair enough.  jQuery is a lightweight framework though and it makes things much easier.  For instance, `$('p').removeClass('myClass yourClass')`  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: yes, i knew how to do it in jquery, but simply didn't want. i don't have a deadline, so i'm not in a hurry, and by using vanilla js i have the chance to get better at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing that `for` loop:

```
for (var i = selected.length; --i >= 0; removeClass(selected[i], 'selected'));
```

The return value from `getElementsByClassName()` is a NodeList, not an array, and it's "live". That means that as you change the DOM by removing the class, you're changing the list too.

By going backwards, you avoid the problem. You could also do this:

```
while (selected.length) removeClass(selected[0], 'selected');
```

By the way the regex you're using to remove the classes could be simpler:

```
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + cls + '\\b', 'g');
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
}
```

In a JavaScript regular expression, `\b` means "word boundary". Also there's no point calling `hasClass()` because the replacement just won't do anything if the class string isn't present.

*edit* — It's pointed out in a comment that this doesn't work for class names with embedded hyphens, a common convention. If you need to deal with that, then I think this would work:

```
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + cls.replace(/-/g, '\\b-\\b') + '\\b', 'g');
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
}
```

or some variation on that theme.

Comment: why by going backwards I avoid the problem? i had one other function like this worked also forwards... thank you for the help, vey much, but i'd love a deeper explaination if it's not a problem.

Comment: When you go forwards incrementing "i", you skip some.  Why?  Because each call to "removeClass()" makes the list shorter by 1.  Thus you only remove the class from every other element of the list.  In other words, after you remove the class from the element at position 0, it won't be in the list anymore, and the element that was at position 1 will then be at position 0.  If you increment "i" to 1, you skip that element.

Comment: I believe using \\b will fail for class names that include a dash, e.g. very-silly-class. At least this is what I'm seeing in IE.

Comment: @Will hey good point - I'll update the answer as soon as I figure out a good way around that problem :-)