# Retrieve display property using javascript and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an expandable div. I want to retrieve the CSS display  property and change it using pure javascript. In doing so I receive an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

```js
var myFunction = function() {   

    var header = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse_header');

    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse_body');
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(hiddenDiv).getPropertyValue('display');
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenDiv.length; i++) {      

        if (theCSSprop.style.display === "block" || theCSSprop.style.display === "") {
            clVal[i].style.display = "none";

        } else {
            theCSSprop.style.display = "block";
        }


        header[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

    }

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction, false);
```

```css
.collapse_wrapper {
    width:500px;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #636428;
    border-radius:18px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:50px;
    float:left;
}

.collapse_header {
    padding:50px;
    width:100%;
    background:#636428;
    font-size:34px;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.collapse_body {
    height:500px;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:90px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="collapse_wrapper">
        <div class="collapse_header">
            Expandable Div 1
        </div>

        <div class="collapse_body">
            The body of div 1
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="collapse_wrapper">
        <div class="collapse_header">
            Expandable Div 2
        </div>

        <div class="collapse_body">
            The body of div 2
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array so hiddenDiv is any array of Elements

Comment: getElementsByClassName akways returns a list. try var hiddenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse_body')[0]  However this will throw if there are no elements found. If you think there's a chance, check for the result before trying to get its css.

Comment: I try that but it's not working. when I click the a div with class "collapse_header" , I want the body section to associated with that div to collapse, not all at once. Also, I have an event handler attach to each header.  header[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working example for what you want to achieve. 
Getting a computed property in a cross browser way is a bit of a pain in the back, if you don't use libraries. So, I think it may be better to set the `display:none` in the javascript.

Here is my code

```
for (var i = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse_body').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('collapse_body')[i].style.display = "none";
};
var l = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse_header');
var toggle = function()
{
    cb = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('collapse_body')[0];
    cb.style.display = ((cb.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none");

}
for (var i = l.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    l[i].addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
};
```

Basically you set the `display` property of all of your `collapse_body` elements to `none`, then attach to every `collapse_header` an event that toggle the display property of his sibling `collapse_body`.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/exvp0202/1/)

Also please note that `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements, which you can map or select an element from as you would do with a normal array.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. The only thing i'm confused about is this line:  for (var i = l.length - 1; i >= 0; i--). Why increment downwards?

Comment: In this case it's not really necessary, but sometimes when manipulating the dom it prevents some bugs. [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411561/removeclass-function-doesnt-work-properly)